# How to know the command line arugments to build a project that was coded in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, command-line

I have a project that I coded in Eclipse, now I need to compile it and run using the terminal. The project has some additional libraries that were added to the linker.

e.g.

> g++ *then what?*

How can I know that command line arguments that I need to run it through the terminal?

The project was coded in c++ using eclipse Luna on a linux machine.

Thanks

Comment: The commands used should be displayed in the build console window, but as Eclipse is a pretty crappy C++ IDE, who knows if they will be.

Comment: I did check that and it giving me this: g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/boost_final_v1.d" -MT"src/boost_final_v1.d" -o "src/boost_final_v1.o" "../src/boost_final_v1.cpp"       and this: g++ -L/usr/include -o "boost_final_v1"  ./src/ahtable.o ./src/boost_final_v1.o ./src/hat-trie.o ./src/misc.o ./src/murmurhash3.o   -lboost_system -lboost_thread

Comment: both do not seem correct

Answer (score 0):

You could always try

```
g++ -std=c++0x your_file_name.cpp -o desired_output_name
```

Comment: I know this usually works but as I said I have added additional libraries (boost thread and boost system) so it did not work for me.

Comment: Maybe you can find some information here. https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html